# Deserializing XML: Is it possible to import more Object containing Lists, where the List Elements are the same objects?

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I serialized some objects, all objects have a list of "LinkObject". These Lists are sharing some of these "Linkobjects". If I deserialize then all list element will be independent, different object.

```
I have a list of "OperationsObjects":
```

```
public class OperationObject
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Physname { get; set; }
        public string JournalID { get; set; }
        public List<ParameterObject> ParameterObjectList = new List<ParameterObject>();
        public List<ConditionObject> ConditionObjectList = new List<ConditionObject>();
        public List<LinkObject> ChildLinkObjectList = new List<LinkObject>();
    }

public class LinkObject
    {
        public int? Number { get; set; }
        public string LogicType { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryID { get; set; }
        public string SecondaryID { get; set; }
    }
```

If I serialize then I got some similar XML lines:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfOperationObjects xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<OperationObjectList>
    <OperationObject Name="step forward">
      <ParameterObjectList />
      <ConditionObjectList />
      <ChildLinkObjectList>
        <LinkObject>
          <Number>0</Number>
          <LogicType>And</LogicType>
          <PrimaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_1]</PrimaryID>
          <SecondaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_2]</SecondaryID>
        </LinkObject>
        <LinkObject>
          <Number>2</Number>
          <LogicType>And</LogicType>
          <PrimaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_3]</PrimaryID>
          <SecondaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_1]</SecondaryID>
        </LinkObject>
      </ChildLinkObjectList>
      <Physname>Program-Parameters</Physname>
      <PhysType>NXOpen.Mechatronics.ProxyObject</PhysType>
      <Duration>2</Duration>
      <StartTime>1</StartTime>
      <OperationType>Simple</OperationType>
      <JournalID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_1]</JournalID>
    </OperationObject>
    <OperationObject Name="118 Component M8">
      <ParameterObjectList />
      <ConditionObjectList />
      <ChildLinkObjectList>
        <LinkObject>
          <Number>0</Number>
          <LogicType>And</LogicType>
          <PrimaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_1]</PrimaryID>
          <SecondaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_2]</SecondaryID>
        </LinkObject>
        <LinkObject>
          <Number>1</Number>
          <LogicType>And</LogicType>
          <PrimaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_2]</PrimaryID>
          <SecondaryID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_4]</SecondaryID>
        </LinkObject>
      </ChildLinkObjectList>
      <Duration>1</Duration>
      <StartTime>3</StartTime>
      <OperationType>Simple</OperationType>
      <JournalID>GanttOperationObject[gantt_2]</JournalID>
    </OperationObject>
```

So I want to have the same Object for LinkObjects with Number 0.
Actually I want to edit the Linkobject in my OperationObject Name="step forward", and My expectation that the LinkObject will be also edited in  OperationObject Name="118 Component M8"

Comment: well, that's a really broad question, cause it doesn't really imply how you want to edit it, or when the editing should be done. Also, how do you assume it will work going forward? What if your step foward changes number 0 to add some things that eventually don't have anything to do anymore with your step 118? I mean, it's definitely doable, just show what you have tried :)

Comment: Editing should be after deserialize, (so the object are living only in the memory) 
"What if your step foward changes number 0 to add some things that eventually don't have anything to do anymore with your step 118?" 
There is no "What if". The number 0-s should be same object. They were the same before the serialization. 
I tried to search some XML Attributes such like XmlElement, XmlAttribute, XmlText, xmlarrayitem, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it automatically. But you should do it manually after deserialization.  You can collect all unique  LinkObjects to separate collection and substitute each related LinkObject  to  OperationObject from this collection by Id (in your case it is Number value).
There is code example. I have used json serializer but actually it does not matter.

```
List<TestParent> parents = new List<TestParent>();
            TestChild child = new TestChild() { Name = "Test" };
            //add to parent class with the same child class;
            parents.Add(new TestParent() { Child = new List<TestChild>() { child } });
            parents.Add(new TestParent() { Child = new List<TestChild>() { child } });
            String data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parents);
            List<TestParent> deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestParent>>(data);
            var comparer = new ChildComparer();
            List<TestChild> brokenLinkCollection = deserializedData.SelectMany(x => x.Child).Distinct().ToList();
            // 2 Child with the same Name
            List<TestChild> uniqueCollection = deserializedData.SelectMany(x => x.Child).Distinct(comparer).ToList();

            var processedChild = deserializedData.Select(x => x.Child).ToList();

            processedChild.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var substitutedCollection = uniqueCollection.Where( uc => x.Contains(uc, comparer)).ToList(); 
                x.Clear();
                x.AddRange(substitutedCollection);
            });

            List<TestChild> resoredCollection = deserializedData.SelectMany(x => x.Child).Distinct().ToList();
            // 1 Child is found due to linking to one memory object
```

used classes:

```
 class ChildComparer : EqualityComparer<TestChild>
    {
        public override bool Equals(TestChild b1, TestChild b2)
        {
            if (b1 == null && b2 == null)
                return true;
            else if (b1 == null || b2 == null)
                return false;

            return (b1.Name == b2.Name);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode(TestChild bx)
        {
            return bx.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    public class TestChild
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
    public class TestParent
    {
        public List<TestChild> Child { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks the example code was not necessary but I am very grateful. :) I thought it is possible to do it automatically. I created a unique List about LinkObjects (simply foreach on the deserialized collection) then with linq I created a list about the Operationobjects, condition was always the LinkObject-Number as you said. It works. :) Thank you again

Comment: Code examples might be useful for other visitors. Unfortunately your question is not be solved with automatic way.